# Find Duplicates in a column with large number (as text)

Tags: excel

I have a SpreadSheet with a column with large number represented as text, and when I apply the duplicate operation to check ( I do not use any formula, I am using excel 2010 in-built functionality of "Conditional Formatting" -->"Highlight Cells Rule" --> "Duplicate Values") even distinct values are shown as duplicate values.

For example:

If I just have following values in a column of spread sheet:

```
26200008004000800000000000000001
26200008004000800000000000000002
26200008004000800000000000000003
```

It shows as all 3 values being duplicate.
How do I fix this and check for duplicates with these large numbers in excel.

P.S: I know excel has a 15 digit limit to precision, but is there a work around or another application to find duplicates.

Comment: What is the "duplicate operation" that you are applying?  The `Remove Duplicates` method does not find any duplicates.

Comment: If somebody downvotes, please have the courtesy to mention the reason.

Comment: Eh, that does not appear to be downvote worthy. I learned a couple things from this post with respect to Excel, VBA and numeric precision. So +1 from me.

Comment: Some people will downvote and remain anonymous.  I disagree with that behavior.  Please see my answer for a method of using Conditional Formatting to highlight your duplicates, that seems to work with long numbers stored as text such as you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that DupUnique property is converting the value to a number. I also note similar behavior with COUNTIF.  Accordingly, I would suggest, in this situation, that you use the conditional format option to use a formula.  The formula I would suggest (assuming that the range to check for duplicates is A2:A10, would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A2=$A$2:$A$10))>1
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a helper column in which I concatenate the number with a letter to make it an alphanumeric entry.

```
=concatenate("a",'large number cell')
```

or

```
="a"&'large number cell'
```

a26200008004000800000000000000001

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

When pasting the numbers into Excel, put an apostrophe in front of the number to convert the number to text like this

```
'26200008004000800000000000000001
```

Thereafter you can do duplicate checks using Data -> Remove Duplicates.

If you already have that kind of data in Excel, it may appear in Exponential values and chances are that Excel chomped it up to [15 digits numeric precision](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f). You may have to re-enter the large data with apostrophe in front of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, adding an apostrophe before the number does the trick, but then it changes the representation, which I cannot afford, Any other ways?

Comment: You could store the character data with apostrophe in one cell, store first 10 digits in the next cell, store next digits in the next and so on. When you need to put data together, use VBA to multiply them and convert back to text. I cannot think of anything else. You could use a database instead like SQLite, Access, MySQL, SQL Server Express or such